# How might i setup my ASP.NET project to find my files?

Tags: asp.net

edit **I do not want to redirect pages, specific files etc. I would like to change the path where images, videos and other media are stored from the root source directory to the directory of my choosing**. In this case c:/dev/prjfiles/prjname/public (c:/dev/prjfiles/prjname/ is my working directory) and i except when my html does img src="/pic.png" it will find the image in c:/dev/prjfiles/prjname/publi/pic.png. I need a working solution, i tried looking at how to set virtual directories and etc. I cant figure it out. Thus the bounty. I am generating the html, **i am not writing** `asp:image runat="server"` etc i am pulling data from a DB and outputing the html. The part that is still a WIP is the code that handles POST request. The html already exist but i cant have hundreds of files in site.com/here pollution my source directory (c:/dev/trunk/thisprj/thisprj/*where my .aspx files are and i do not wish 500 .png/gif/jpg here*)

I dont know how asp.net environments are usually set up. I am assuming i have a root path that is not available from the web, a bin/ where i may put my asp.net dll and a public where i stick in any files i want.

I would like to have my project files seperated from everything else. My JS, css and image files are in prjfiles/prjname/public with my sqlite db in prjfiles/prjname/ and extra binaries in prjfiles/prjname/bin.

The problem comes when i run my app and try to load an image. Such as /cssimg/error.png. My project does not find resource in my /public folder and i have no idea how to make it find them. How can i set my project up so it does?

NOTE: I set the working directory path so its at prjfiles/prjname/. In code i write ./bin/extrabin.exe and db.sqlite3 which access the files properly.

Comment: I think your assumptions are basically flawed - what development tools are you using?

Comment: Can you explain how you reference images that cannot be found. I saw a lot of answers based on assumptions, but i think this will nail the problem down.

Comment: ljubomir: ? i generate html and link them as `<img src="/img.png">`. The file is NOT located in my root source directory. Its in ./public/ relative to my working directory which is something like c:/dev/prjfiles/prjname/

Comment: Is the question solved right now?

Comment: No. I still cant figure out how to have my png in any directory i want and have my webpage refer to them as "/folder/img.png"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to watch the getting started videos for ASP.NET

http://www.asp.net/get-started/

**EDIT:** More info added

As @Murph suggests, your assumptions are incorrect.
IIS takes care of blocking HTTP access to any important files and folders like your *.aspx.cs, and *.cs in the App_Code, any DLLs, anything under the App_Data directory and the web.config.

Content files, such as *.html, *.css, *.js, .gif, .jpg, .png are all served in the normal manner.

In this way, there is no need for a "public" folder.

Comment: Good to know. However i still like them separate. I dont use automated binary backups in my source folders (it would pick up objs, exes, etc and other junk. and i cant blacklist because i may want them when i put them in my binary prj folder)

Answer (score 4):

> I dont know how asp.net environments are usually set up. I am assuming i have a root path that is not available from the web, a bin/ where i may put my asp.net dll and a public where i stick in any files i want.

This is wrong assumption!

- You have a root folder, which IS available in public. You set IIS or ASP.NEt Development Server to this folder.
- (optional, but always needed) You have a web.config file in this root folder for configuration
- You have a bin folder for your assemblies (each page or user control "include" compiles to a class)
- (optional) You have App_Data as default folder for file-based DBs and/or other data files (say XML storage, ..)
- (optional) You have an App_theme folder for styling and images. Read about ASP.NET themes.
- (optional) You can add App_Code folder if you want to add classes to be compiled by the server.
- You can create folders for scripts, etc...

Normally for complex logic, etc.. you create in a separate project outside the root and reference the result assembly in the bin folder.

Seriously, you cannot do ASP.NET work without an IDE or a manual. Visual Web Developer 2008 Express IDE is free and http://asp.net has tons of resources for getting started.

Comment: I'm liking this answer. You almost answered my questions. If the user uploads files and i do not want it accessible to the web, where should i put it? App_Data? (I am not on my dev machine ATM so i'll ask) If i put base.css and accept.png in App_theme will the image show up if i write `<img src="/accept.png">`?

Comment: You put it in any folder, and use the web.config file to make settings for this folder to be denied from everybody. Google (or Bing!) for <location> and <authorization> tags in web.config

Comment: And by the way, if you are using a server control like <asp:image runat="server" ... you can use "~/" as a relative notation that refers to your web root folder. I'm sorry but the guys were right about the need to check the introduction material on http://asp.net

Comment: It looks like location redirects pages. I dont want to redirect a page but set the path to my images. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I got the question right, but maybe you could try the `<BASE>` HTML tag.

> HTML `<base>` Tag
>
> "Specify a default URL and a default target for all links on a page"

There's a nice and simple example at W3Schools, [check it out](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp).

The negative side is that you need to put a `<BASE>` tag in each page you want.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be able to create a virtual directory to do what you're asking -- but it's a very non-standard setup.

Keep in mind that IIS will prevent users from downloading DLLs and other project-level files, so you usually don't need to partition them off in a separate layer.

For example, just have a cssimg folder at the top level of your project, and skip the whole public folder thing.

Comment: Theres tons of files in root. This would pollute my source directory. Also i prefer to keep source and binary separate. I dont automate binary/resource backups in my source directory. How do i create these virtual directories? i tried but failed.

Answer (score 1):

I see where you're coming from. ASP.NET projects are set up a little differently from how you're treating them, but you can make them work like you want.

The root of an ASP.NET project *IS* publicly accessible. When you created your WebSite within Visual Studio, it created a default.aspx page right on the root. Are you hosting in IIS? If so, it's set up to serve up default.aspx by default. But I digress.


Here's how to make it work like you want (mostly):

Create a WebSite, then right-click the site and add a folder named "prjfiles". Right-click that folder and make another named "public". Create another subfolder of that one called "cssimg".

Now, if you want to use the image you mentioned, you'd reference it like this: "~/prjfiles/public/cssimg/error.png" (pathing starting with the root) or "./cssimg/error.png" if you're coming from a page in the public folder (relative pathing).


Really, though, you're doing too much work. Here's how to make it work with less effort:

Create your WebSite, right-click the project and add a folder called "cssimg".

Treat the root as you would the "public" folder- put your pages right there on the root or in subfolders, as needed. You can reference that same image file like this now: "./cssimg/error.png" (relative) or "~/cssimg/error.png" (start from root)


There's also another way to tell the engine where to look for resources, but it's for your css files. Inside the "head" tag, you can add a "style" element (with type="text/css") and inside that you can add something like this: @import '<%= ResolveUrl("~/prjfiles/public/cssimg/styles.css") %>';


Good luck!

Comment: "you'd reference it like this: "~/prjfiles/public/cssimg/error.png" (pathing starting with the root)" <-- i am generating html and not writing it out. The generated results expects src="/img.png" to be in public (right now that file is sitting with my source to work properly. I rather have imgs away from the source). This answer looks correct but how do i make it look in <somewhere>/public/ for this file?

Comment: why just not add "/public" in front of the referenced file (src="/public/img.png"). What you're after relies on url rewriting and this is soo easier and feels like the natural way asp.net is operating.

Comment: I tried URL rewriting and i am forced to set the mime of each type :X. I notice right away my CSS file wasn't working as it was set to text and not text/css. Also people will be able to access the non public media if they ignore the /public and guess the path. Also for favicon.ico must still be in the root directory and not /public with the rest of my media.

Comment: I think it all goes back to relative versus absolute pathing. You can use a ~/ to tell the engine to start at the root of the site or you can use the ./ or just / to start with the current directory or a ../ to go up a directory. I hope I'm understanding your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your problem, you're trying to find files which aren't physically stored on a filesystem folder, or stay on a different folder. You can deal with this problems by implementing a `UrlRewrite` mechanism.

I suggest you to read [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) and, after, to take a look into this implementation: [A Complete URL Rewriting Solution for ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=357).

Comment: IIRC last time when i did this the MIME for each type was broken. I tried it again now and it looks fine... I wonder why it was broken before. Now i need to disable the rewrite when i upload it to my server. hmm... I think this is a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand all this correctly (please comment with any correction) right now all your files are together in the root directory and you use `<img src="/img.png" />` and it works.

If this is the case, make another directory in the directory the images are in, say call that directory `images` and put the image files there.  now use `<img src="/images/img.png" />`.

Done.

Comment: The problem is the html is generated so i'll have to grab the output then filter it all. I thought of and tried a global redirect. It works however i lose the MIME and need to hand set them which i dislike as well. Thus setting the resource path in VS/IIS is the most reasonable solution but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: This should work if you generate html too.  You can create an html file in visual studio (nto .aspx) and then drag the image in to see what the path should look like.

Comment: i mean like. The html with links already exist and i am pulling it from a table. I would have to parse the links if i wanted to do this. Instead of simply just doing response.Write()